# Pythonic way of "inner join" of list of lists with arbitrary lengths?

Tags: python, list, set, set-intersection

I have an arbitrary list of lists, for example

```
x = [
        [5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [5, 10, 11, 12]
    ]
```

There is only one element which is a member of all three lists in x = `5`

My question: **What is the most pythonic method of testing membership of elements in an arbitrary number of lists?**

My solution is as follows, but feels like it could be simpler:

```
y = x[0]
if len(x) > 1:
    for subset in x[1:]:
        x = list(set(x) & set(subset))
```

EDIT: The output should be a list with the common elements included.
For the example above, it would be `[5]`
If the example above had two elements (e.g. 5 and foo) the output should be `[5, "foo"]`

Comment: What exactly should the result be for this input? What should the result be when the lists have multiple common elements? What should the result be when the lists have no common elements?

Comment: Why tag (SQL) [tag:inner-join]? You maybe mean, treating each array as a 1-column table you want to repeatedly inner join on equality of that column & project away a copy of the column, ie you want natural join them together. But you are not explaining why you have tagged so.

Comment: It *seems as though* you are simply asking to find out *what the common elements are*, but that is a long way away from a database "inner join".

Comment: Or you maybe mean you want [tag:set-intersection] of the arrays seen as sets seen as an array?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the most *pythonic* way would be to use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) directly:

```py
common = set(x[0]).intersection(*x[1:])
```

---

Regarding **performance**: It depends! (It depends, imho, on how likely it is that there are, in fact, common elements.)

I've tried the following measurement setup:

```py
from functools import reduce
from random import randint, choices, seed
from timeit import timeit

def sample(num_numbers, num_lists, seed_number):
    numbers = list(range(num_numbers))
    seed(seed_number)
    return [choices(numbers, k=randint(50, 100)) for _ in range(num_lists)]

def test_1(x):
    result = set(x[0])
    for sublist in x[1:]:
        result = result.intersection(sublist)

def test_2(x): [val for val in x[0] if all(val in ls for ls in x[1:])]
def test_3(x): reduce(lambda y, z: y.intersection(set(z)), x, set)
def test_4(x): set(x[0]).intersection(*x[1:])

for num_numbers, num_lists in ((3, 10_000), (30, 10_000)):
    print(f"\nSample configuration: {num_numbers = }, {num_lists = }\n")
    x = sample(num_numbers, num_lists, 123456789)
    for n in range(1, 5):
        t = timeit(f"test_{n}(x)", globals=globals(), number=100)
        print(f"test_{n}(x): {t:.3f} seconds")
```

Result here:

```
Sample configuration: num_numbers = 3, num_lists = 10000

test_1(x): 1.227 seconds
test_2(x): 8.817 seconds
test_3(x): 1.094 seconds
test_4(x): 1.193 seconds

Sample configuration: num_numbers = 30, num_lists = 10000

test_1(x): 0.748 seconds
test_2(x): 0.360 seconds
test_3(x): 1.428 seconds
test_4(x): 0.679 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Another, potentially more *pythonic* way of achieving this is:

```py
results = [val for val in x[0] if all(val in ls for ls in x[1:])]
```

This creates a new list of all `val`s in the first sublist (`x[0]`) if the value is also in all lists (`ls`) in all other sublists (`x[1:]`).

This could be considered a more *pythonic* method as it uses only raw python, rather than say, using `functools.reduce` (as suggested in another answer).
It also demonstrates python's unique ability to create a list other list(s) based on a certain condition.

Comment: This is a very slow solution. The for loop is superior to it (it may even be superior to the `functools.reduce` method, but not in terms of complexity). This method will iterature over each element in `x[1:]` `len(x[0])` times, whereas the for loop / functools solutions will iterate over each element in each sublist exactly one.

Comment: @Kraigolas In all tests I have performed (using random dataset of length 10000 with each sublist containing 100 random numbers from `random.randint(1, 100000)`, my solution executed faster than both the for loop and `functools.reduce`.  The for loop took approximately `0.5s` on average, functools took approximately `0.4s`, and my solution was shown as `"00:00:00"` every time. (used `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` to obtain time values)

Comment: After reviewing Timus's timeit results, I've reviewed this solution, and while in practice when there are many numbers that belong to all lists, this solution can be slow, it turns out that because `all` short-circuits, this solution can actually be faster than the other solutions. That is, while this has a much worse worst-case complexity, the best case complexity (and probably the average case as well) is actually much better than looping over all lists! +1 good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to solve this problem:

```
functools.reduce(lambda y, z: y.intersection(set(z)), x, set)
# {5}
```